# How Do I Create Special Fields For Users In Django

Tags: python, django, model

I'm new to Django and I want to create an app where artistes can post their songs and albums. Now I want artistes to have a different sign-up page from the normal users. I want artistes to be able to add their portraits, genres,  and all that. Is there a way to add these fields to the User model? I've seen some questions on this but I don't think I really understood the answers.

Answer (score 3):

There are basicly two ways to achive this:

**1. Create a new model `Artist` with a OneToOneField to the django user model. This is most likely what you want. E.g. like this:**

```python
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Artist(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    genres = models.ManyToManyField('myapp.Genre', related_name='artists')


class Portrait(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey('myapp.Artist', related_name='portraits')


class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

**2. Specify a custom User model that inherits from `AbstractBaseUser`. This is only reccomended if you want to store additional information related to authentication itself.**

I suggest that you read the documentation on this carefully:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

To create a custom sign-up page you will need to create your own `FormView` with a custom template e.g. using the django built in `UserCreationForm` and/or `ModelForm`. You could extend it with whichever fields you need. There are several ways to achive this depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, I think I'll go with the first one. When I'm creating a sign-up form is it possible to display the Artist fields with that of the user?